# 'variable' is not defined by pylance(Python)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am programming with python in ubuntu and i am a noob in the language. I am getting this error that i dont understant because the variable is created as a global variable but the function doesnt recognize it.

```
class BowlingGame():
    
    score = 0
    def roll(self, points):
        score += points
    
    def score(self):
        return score
```

I tried to create a constructor of the class and make it like a tribute of the class but that wasn't what i am aiming for

Comment: _" variable is created as a global variable"_ no, it's not. `score` is a class attribute of `BowlingGame`. In any case, without a `global` or `nonlocal` statement, `score += points` will _always_ refer to a local variable named `score`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: score is a local variable to the score function to assign and get the score variable you should use `self.score`

Comment: The way you've defined it, `score` is a _class attribute_, meaning it is shared among _all_ instances of the class.  Did you really intend that?

Comment: Also, `def score(self):` You can't have a function and an attribute named the same thing.  Pick a different name for one of them.

Comment: Also, `class` statements don't define a new scope. The variable `score` is *only* defined in the namespace constructed by the `class` statements in order to pass to the metaclass that defines the type. After that, the variable is gone. It's not accessible to the methods as a global (or non-local) variable.

Comment: Please read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html, especially the section on classes.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you meant to make `score` be an *instance attribute*, so that each *instance* of the class can have its own separate score:

```
class BowlingGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0

    def roll(self, points):
        self.score += points
```